# How to use awk to read data between all frequent time intervals

Tags: bash, unix, awk, unix-timestamp

My log file has following format

```
[30/Jan/2015:10:10:30 +0000] 12.30.30.204 xff=- reqId=[-] status_check len=- GET /api/getstatus HTTP/1.1 mi=- ec=- 200 425
[30/Jan/2015:10:11:00 +0000] 12.30.30.204 xff=- reqId=[-] status_check len=- GET /api/getstatus HTTP/1.1 mi=- ec=- 200 261
[30/Jan/2015:10:11:29 +0000] 12.30.30.204 xff=- reqId=[-] status_check len=- GET /api/getstatus HTTP/1.1 mi=- ec=- 200 232
[30/Jan/2015:10:12:00 +0000] 12.30.30.204 xff=- reqId=[-] status_check len=- GET /api/getstatus HTTP/1.1 mi=- ec=- 200 315
[30/Jan/2015:10:12:29 +0000] 12.30.30.204 xff=- reqId=[-] status_check len=- GET /api/getstatus HTTP/1.1 mi=- ec=- 200 221
[30/Jan/2015:10:12:57 +0000] 12.30.30.182 xff=- reqId=[-] status_check len=- GET /api/getstatus HTTP/1.1 mi=- ec=- 200 218
```

Each line in this log file has timestamp in first field and response time in the last field. Is there a way in `awk` to read the average response time in all specific intervals? For example, calculating avg response time in every five minutes based on the timestamp in log file.

Or is there any best alternative way to do this other than `awk`? Please suggest.

**Update:**

I have tried the following way which is static way of doing it and will give only average of one time interval.

```
$ grep "30/Jan/2015:10:1[0-4]" mylog.log | awk '{resp+=$NF;cnt++;}END{print "Avg:"int(resp/cnt)}'
```

But I need to do it for the whole file for all 5 minutes. Even if I loop the command, how can I pass the date dynamically to the command? Because the log file varies every time and the dates in it.

Comment: @Jotne. Added to the question. Please have a look.

Comment: You never need grep if you are using awk since awk can do anything useful that grep can do

Comment: @EdMorton, Ya I am aware of that, but I was not able to find awk timestamp parsing script while trying this, so tried with grep initially.

Comment: You just need to escape the backslashes since thats awk regexp delimiter `grep "30/Jan/2015:10:1[0-4]" mylog.log | awk '{foo}'` -> `awk '/30\/Jan\/2015:10:1[0-4]/{foo}' mylog.log`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm. GNU date does not like your date format, so I guess we'll have to parse it ourselves. I'm thinking along these lines (this requires gawk for `mktime`):

```
# returns the seconds since epoch that stamp represents. This will be
# the first field in the line, with [] and everything. It's rather
# rudimentary:
function parse_timestamp(stamp) {
  # Split stamp into tokens delimited by [, ], /, : or space
  split(stamp, c, "[][/: ]")

  # reassemble (using the lookup table for the months from below) in a
  # format that mktime understands (then call mktime).
  return mktime(c[4] " " mnums[c[3]] " " c[2] " " c[5] " " c[6] " " c[7])
}

BEGIN {
  # parse_timestamp needs this lookup table.
  split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec", mnames)
  for(i = 1; i <= length(mnames); ++i) {
    mnums[mnames[i]] = i
  }

  # time is a parameter supplied by you.
  start = parse_timestamp(time)
  end   = start + 300

  if(start == -1) {
    print "Warning: Could not parse timestamp \"" time "\""
  }
}

{ 
  # in each line: parse the timestamp
  curtime = parse_timestamp($1)
}

# if it lies in the interval you want, sum up the last field and increase
# the counter
curtime >= start && curtime < end {
  sum += $NF
  ++count
}

END {
  # and in the end, print the average.
  print "Avg: " (count == 0 ? "undef" : sum / count)
}
```

Put this in a file, say `average.awk`, and call

```
awk -v time='[30/Jan/2015:10:11:20 +0000]' -f average.awk foo.log
```

If you are sure the log file will be sorted in ascending order (which is probably the case), you could make this more efficient by replacing

```
curtime >= start && curtime < end {
  sum += $NF
  ++count
}
```

with

```
curtime >= end {
  exit
}

curtime >= start {
  sum += $NF
  ++count
}
```

This will stop searching for fitting log entries after the first one was found that's after the range you were looking for.

Addendum: Since OP clarified that he wanted Summaries for all five minute intervals in a sorted makefile, a tweaked script to do that is

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

function parse_timestamp(stamp) {
  split(stamp, c, "[][/: ]")
  return mktime(c[4] " " mnums[c[3]] " " c[2] " " c[5] " " c[6] " " c[7])
}

BEGIN {
  split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec", mnames)
  for(i = 1; i <= length(mnames); ++i) {
    mnums[mnames[i]] = i
  }
}

{ 
  curtime = parse_timestamp($1)
}

NR == 1 {
  # pull the start time from the first line
  start = curtime
  end   = start + 300
}

curtime > end {
  # print result, reset counters when endtimes are past
  print "Avg: " (count == 0 ? "undef" : sum / count)
  sum   = 0
  count = 0
  end  += 300
}

{
  sum += $NF
  ++count
}

END {
  # print once more at the very end for the last, unfinished interval.
  print "Avg: " (count == 0 ? "undef" : sum / count)
}
```

Comment: Plus 1 for the approach but you don't need that split/loop/mnames/mnums array - you can map a month name abbrevation to it's number with just `number=(index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",name)+2)/3`.

Comment: This works perfect for one particular interval. But I wanted avg for every five minutes in the log. For that i have made some changes in your code. In `curtime >= end{exit}` I've replace the script to `curtime >= end{end=curtime+300;print "Avg: " (count == 0 ? "undef" : sum / count);sum=count=0;`

Comment: That would work, yes. And instead of passing `-v time=foo`, you could put `NR == 1 { start = curtime }` after the `{ curtime = parse_timestap($1) }` block to start with the timestamp at the beginning of the log file.

Comment: Will you update that in the answer? So that the answer would point to right question.

Comment: Done. Sorry for the delay, I got caught up in meatspace.

Comment: @Wintermute, Never mind of delay. Thanks for the response. Will do a round of testing and will give a response. And as an add-on, I've tried another 'awk' solution too. But this one was quite faster & I'm impressed a lot. Thanks again. :)